# I want to murder all humans

Tags: single-word-requests

Ok, not really. But I was wondering what the appropriate word is for that; "Genocide" applies to murdering all people of a certain race, while "Omnicide" means ending all life. What is the correct word for wanting to kill all members of a certain species? (Does it matter if it's humans, or would eliminating the dodos also use the same word?)

Comment: Technically speaking I suppose it would be *homicide* if the species is homo sap, *bovicide* if you wanted to do away with cows, etc. I don't think there are many real-world referents for the general case of "species-specific killer". In principle I guess I'm one myself, being a committed [vespicidal maniac](http://www.pestaway.com.au/pest-control-technician.html) (though shalt not suffer a **wasp** to live, and all that), but I wouldn't want to get lumped together with people who're fanatical about killing slugs, spiders, or whatever.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers: you just prefix the Latin name of the species. (Vespidae, ixodida, and nematocera deserve to be cided. And maybe Brachycera too. My preferred method for wasps in restaurants is cutting their waist with a knife when they're eating my food. All other small animals are my friends, more or less.)

Comment: @Cerberus: You are a true "brother in arms"! Okay - as soon as we've done the wasps, we'll start on the ticks, etc. Bill Gates is still busy with his [culicide](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Culicidae) project (mosquitoes), but I'm sure he'll join us once he's finished them off.

Comment: [Benderism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bender_%28Futurama%29)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Wouldn't bovicide be killing *one* cow? because homicide is usually killing one person.

Comment: @Sean McMillan: I don't really think so. It's just that we don't normally have a real-world referent for the act of killing *all* members of a species. When they all die, we usually call the process an *extinction*, and we say the species *became extinct*. You could say there are no words for actively eliminating a whole species, but if OP wants one, I don't see why the existing stock of current and validly-generatable words can't have the extended sense. Cerberus would be no use to the cause if he only wants to kill *one wasp!*

Answer (score 4):

Extermination might help in your, er, endeavour.

[Extermination](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exterminate):

> to get rid of completely usually by killing off

Comment: +1 - accurate and can be used in place of *genocide*

Answer (score 1):

In Science Fiction contexts, **Genocide** has been used to refer to eliminating an entire species. An example of this is in the Star Trek episode [I Borg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Borg), many object to commiting genocide against the Borg.

Comment: **Genocide**, which literally means "race killing", means the extermination of a particular race or lineage of humanity. I have never seen *genocide* used to describe the extermination of *all* races or lineages. Science fiction stories often propose the existence of more than one sentient race or species (on an even footing with humanity). In such a context, *genocide* describes the extermination of a particular race or lineage of sentient beings, but not *all* such races or lineages.

Comment: The variant **Xenocide** is a novel by O. S. Card.

Answer (score 1):

I think your dodo example is revealing - seems like *extinction* should do fine. If you want to kill all humans, then you want to *cause human extinction*, or *make humans extinct.*. And you could insert any other species in that template.

Comment: If the OP wants a term that can be used in place of *genocide* then *extinction* doesn't quite fit. It describes not the act but the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

@LarsTech's answer is good. Another good word is **extirpation**. This word, which literally means *rooting out*, is the usual translation for the word Hitler used (`ausrotten`, to root out).

Answer (score 0):

One logical construction would be *speciecide*, which gets a few Google hits (although not many). I think you have to ask yourself whether you mind using a neologism.

Comment: *Speciecide* does not say which of the species, though. OP refers to a specific species to be indicated: the title is as self-explanatory as it is shocking. :)

Comment: @Kris, *genocide* doesn't say which race, *homicide* doesn't say which person. I don't see that as a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to make up a word but the Latin Sapien seems to refer to all those possesing the characteristics of Homo-sapiens so I would suggest Sapiocide? Or come variation of that although probably means the same as homocide in that it only applies to the death of one.

I think Genocide is actually correct as we are still all one Genus even if you can break us up into sub genus'