# when to use "of" and when not?

Tags: prepositions

I have a question:
it's been months that I watch movies for improving my listening skill(it was quite awful:-D). now my question. I know that we should use "warlord" instead of "Lord of war" or "landlord" instead of "Lord of land" but I don't know why "The lord of the rings" is correct? isn't it better to use Ringslord ???
 I meant how to know when I should use "of" ?

Comment: It would be "ringlord" and not "ringslord", because *s* is usually dropped when combining words. But apart from that, I think it was an arbitrary decision that Tolkien made. And in fact, searching his books, Tolkien did use "Ringlord" at least once in them. So I think the answer is that if there's an established phrase, you should use it (assuming it means what you want it to). And otherwise, it doesn't matter.

Comment: *The Lord of the Rings* was published in the mid-50s, about the same time as William Golding's *Lord of the Flies*. I can just about imagine **Ringlord** might have worked, but **Flylord**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: As I suggested in my answer, I don't think "Ringlord" would have been possible in the 50s: I think it's an example of a formation which has arisen since, within the genre of "fantasy" which Lin Carter and others invented on the back of Tolkien.

Comment: @Colin Fine: You're quite right, of course. Forms like *warlord, sealord, landlord* were around a long time ago, but the mechanism only really become productive again to generate *timelord, ringlord, druglord, slumlord* maybe 30-40 years ago. But I *still* doubt that if Golding were writing today he'd opt for **Flylord**!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: actually I don't think "sealord" was. The OED lists "sea-lord" (not "sealord") but all three of the examples it cites use "sea lord" (not "sea-lord")!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Warlord" and "landlord" are English words.

"Lord of war" and "lord of land" do not happen to be established English phrases, but they can certainly be used: but they do not mean the same as the words. (For example, a "landlord" may be quite a humble person, provided only that they have some property which is let to somebody else - and that is leaving aside the special meaning of "landlord" as "publican" or "proprietor of a pub").

In a feudal setting, you could reasonably use the phrase "lord of the land" - this would mean the lord who ruled over the land: a quite different meaning from "landlord".

In the case the Rings, neither "Ringlord" nor "Lord of the rings" existed in English before Tolkien wrote them, as far as I know. We cannot know why he used the phrase for the title, but my guess is

1. it has a more sonorous sound
2. at the time he wrote it, I think that using a neologism like "Ringlord" in the title of a book would have puzzled both editors and readers.

Answer (score 2):

Convention. When a given term becomes standard currency for a set of users, that usage is considered correct. Take, for example, "it's me" vs. 'it is I". Most people would accept that "it's me" is the modern conventional form, and therefore correct. Whereas, some might reject "it is I" as archaic.

There are basically two kinds of grammarians: prescriptive and descriptive. Prescriptive essentially means that rules are derived from theory. Descriptive means that rules are deduced from practice.

Thus, the short response to your question is that you should go with what is conventional usage. Usually, you'll find such to be generally acceptable (intelligible) to most users with whom you intend to communicate.

Comment: That's not really what those words mean. A descriptive text or utterance or attitude describes things without assigning value or preference to them; a prescriptive text, etc., assigns value and/or preference.

Comment: The point is "grammar" and the approach one takes in its application. Thus, "meaning" here, as used by you is prescriptive and normative, i.e. taken from a book and presented as binding. It assigns value based on a priori, theoretical conjecture. However, the "meaning" that I described arises from the approach taken in arriving at a given conclusion regarding language usage. To reiterate. Descriptive grammar seeks to discover rules. Prescriptive grammar seeks to create rules to which others are expected to adhere.

Comment: You prescribe this definition, I prescribe another. They are both prescriptive.

Comment: I describe a usage, based on observation, and argue on behalf of the legitimacy of such usage to co-exist among others, given its de facto existence. That is descriptive grammar. You prescribe a usage, and argue against the legitimacy of others to co-exist, as they do not comply with your prescription. That is prescriptive grammar. You prescribe what should be, I describe what is. There is a salient difference in our approaches.

Comment: Describing a usage is one thing, arguing on the behalf of its legitimacy quite another. Arguing with me is not describing; if you were purely descriptive, you would just smile and nod.

Comment: All that is required for evil to prevail is that good people smile and nod as you prescribe. Describing would be irrelevant if it did not include the logical step of recognizing and championing the legitimacy of that which one describes. I would exceedingly regret the loss of rich language that is certain to result from compliance with your prescriptions.

Comment: @Cerberus: I'm afraid you'll need to be a bit more explicit in your "prescriptivist" position, 'cos I can't make out exactly what it is. (I only want to know so I can disagree with it, obviously! :)

Comment: @JackRobbin: That is absolutely fine, and I support your position to a considerable extent. I just think that this logical conclusion, while based on description much more than certain style books with a more theoretical approach, is itself also prescriptive. And there is nothing wrong with that; how else can one advise readers? Only an article in a linguistic journal is exclusively descriptive. Perhaps the dichotomy you are interested in can be described as empirical versus theoretical? Based on corpus versus principle? Oh, well, perhaps it doesn't matter. P.S. One of the up-votes is mine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, there it is! I object to the idea that advice can be given without prescription, because it obscures the aesthetic, social, and moral elements that influence the kind of advice we give.

Comment: @Cerberus: oic - yes, I guess all "advice" about language usage is prescriptive, if you put it like that. I think I'm generally descriptive/tolerant, but I kinda take it for granted that advice primarily intended to avoid someone being either misunderstood or classified as an "incompetent speaker" isn't really in the same league as nitpicking over the finer points of grammar, semantics, logic, etc. Dammit! - I'm prolly a closet prescriptivist after all!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, see, that slash betrayed you: you treat "descriptive" and "tolerant" as contextually identical. What you mentioned may not be in the same "league" as nitpicking, but it is still not without any prescription! That was my point.

Comment: @Cerberus: Your point is well made. I'll just have to live with the fact that because I'm an *opinionated so-and-so / helpful guy*, I can never again claim to be a descriptivist! (except with people who just "smile and nod" :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That seems wise; now convince the rest of the world!

Comment: @Cerberus: All in good time. You and I have yet to convince the rest of the world to [rise up and take arms against wasps](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50728/i-want-to-murder-all-humans)

Comment: @Cerberus - I think you've missed a point and created a fallacy.  I spoke of the contrast between prescriptive and descriptive grammar. You appear to have interpreted this position to mean that I am a descriptive grammarian, and, moreover, am limited to acting in that capacity. Nothing could be further from the truth, which is: I am a language user, a bearer of this language. It is in this capacity that I raised the issue of descriptive versus prescriptive grammar. However, I never abandoned my right to freely comment on matters grammatical, or otherwise, as I please. The same right you have.

Comment: @JackRobbin: Oh, if my conclusion about your being descriptive was too hasty, I apologize. Never did I mean to say that you should not comment or advise.